# Welcome message in the terminal

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, terminal, root

I'm trying to create a script that shows a welcome message when the root user enters the terminal.

My current problem is that the welcome message also gets shown if a normal user starts the terminal...

Anyone any sugestions? See my script below:

```
if (whoami=$root) 

then echo "Welcome in the terminal"

fi
```

Comment: you could print a message from root's shell profile file -- .bashrc or whatever.

Comment: That is syntactically wrong. It's generally helpful if you also include the error message(s) you get when you run your code

Comment: `if [[ "$(whoami)" == "root" ]] ; then` ?

Comment: `id -u` is an alternative command you can use. root user has id 0.

Comment: @roaima the script you provided worked for me. I'm now trying to find out what the differences are between our two scripts and hope to be able to create one myself!

I aprecciate it everyone!